# concate writes the data twice

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE p_candidate SET  `med_comt` = CONCAT_WS(`med_comt`,' ','$_POST[med_comt]') where `candidate_id` = '$_POST[candidate_id]'");
```

what I am trying to do is use concat so that the new comments are added to the database without overwriting existing comments.

The new comments are not being separated by a space and the new comments get written twice. for example if the existing comment is 'this is a test' and the new comment is 'another one!'

the new data looks like this

> this is a testanother one!another one!

what I want is :

> this is a test another one!

It would be better if I could get the new comment on a new line like this:

> this is a test
>
> another one!

Thanks

Comment: Please escape your input, and your queries: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `CONCAT_WS` as if it were `CONCAT`. `CONCAT_WS` works differently. Your first argument should be the SEPARATOR, and your remaining arguments are the values which get split via the SEPARATOR.

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE p_candidate SET  `med_comt` = CONCAT_WS(' ', `med_comt`, '$_POST[med_comt]') where `candidate_id` = '$_POST[candidate_id]'");
```

PS: Please sanitize or prepare your data.

Comment: You really should remove the `$_POST` variables from your answer and replace it with a placeholder value. This sort of thing will get you burned in a huge way if you use it in its current form.

Comment: Once he gets an sql injection, he'll remember to sanitize his input next time :]

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special form of CONCAT(). The **first** argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments.

Try

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE p_candidate SET  `med_comt` = CONCAT_WS(' ',`med_comt`,' ','$_POST[med_comt]') where `candidate_id` = '$_POST[candidate_id]'");
```

Also please NEVER use user supplied data directly in sql queries without at least escaping it before use. eg by using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Please note the big warning box on the php manual pages for mysql_* functions though, Really you should change to using mysqli_* functions or PDO if at all possible

Comment: It's good to point out the escape function, but it's imperative you use it in your answer to demonstrate it.